# How to fail cypress test from inside the Promise.prototype.catch() block?

Tags: promise, try-catch, cypress, cypress-task

I'm using a node library to execute api calls for test data setup and teardown. The library works as follows:

```js
someApiServiceObject
.executeApiCall({... parameters})
.then(doSomethingWithResults())
.catch(() => { 
  // Here I would like to fail the test as something has gone wrong
})
```

If the request fails for some reason, I only learn about it by the Promise returning from `executeApiCall` function being rejected - hence the catch block.

But if I put `throw new Error();` into the catch block or remove the catch block, I can see the `(uncaught exception) Error:` in the cypress console, but the test still passes.

Can someone advise me on how this case should be handled correctly?

The test:

```js
it('List projects', () => {
    projectsApi.projectsList({})
      .then(() => {
        cy.log('Success');
      }).catch(() => {
        throw new Error();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Can you show the entire cypress test code please?

Comment: You'll need to `return` the promise from your `it` callback

Answer (score 1):

If you call `someApiServiceObject.executeApiCall({...parameters})` in a task (since it's a node library), you should just be able to return the promise and Cypress handles failing the test. Don't `catch()` within the task.

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    api(parameters) {
      return someApiServiceObject
        .executeApiCall({... parameters})
        .then(doSomethingWithResults())   
    },
  })
}
```

If that fails, follow this pattern [Return number of files in the folder](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Return-number-of-files-in-the-folder)

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    countFiles(folderName) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        someApiServiceObject
          .executeApiCall({... parameters})
          .then(doSomethingWithResults())
          .then((results) => resolve(results))
          .catch((err) => reject(err))
        })
      })
    },
  })
}
```

---

From comments, I think there's a assumption being made that `.executeApiCall()` must be returning a promise, but that may not be the case.

For example `cy.get(...)` has a `.then(...)` method, but it does not return a promise, it just has a `.then()` method.

If `.executeApiCall()` does actually return a promise, the first example is all you need. If it does not, you need to wrap the code.

Cypress will recognise a promise returned from a task, and use `resolve` or `reject` accordingly.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: It's from the Cypress docs.

Comment: That's not a justification for writing bad code, it just means they should also fix their docs :-)

Comment: LOL not just Cypress docs, see  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises). Where does this antipattern stuff come from?

Comment: I think there's a assumption being made that `someApiServiceObject.executeApiCall()` has to return a promise, but that would be erroneous. For example `cy.get(...).then(...)` does not return a promise, it just has a `.then()` method. If it does return a promise, the first example is all you need. If it does not, you need to wrap it.